# Not able to get the newly typed values from the input box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table row containing two input boxes and a button. On clicking that button I need to get the newly typed value that the user has typed in the input box. So I'm doing it this way.

```
<tr>
  <!-- Input box row (for new row input) -->
  <td><input type="text" id="new_E" value="Enter new text"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="new_I" value="Enter new text"></td>
  <td><button class="add" onclick="add_row()">Add row</button></td>
</tr>
```

And the `add_row()` function looks like this:

```
function add_row()
{
  //Step 1: Getting what the user typed in the new row
  var new_E=document.getElementById("new_E").value;
  var new_I=document.getElementById("new_I").value;
  console.log("User typed this:"+ new_E);
}
```

Now after typing a new value in the input boxes also, this is what I'm seeing in the console:

```
User typed this: Enter new text
```

I can't figure out why the new values of the input boxes in not being returned by `document.getElementById("new_E").value` inside `add_row()` function.
I know this is very basic but it's not working for me. Can you please help me figure out what's going wrong here. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I figured out the issue. Actually I have the <tr> </tr> in a loop. So my DOM had multiple instances of <tr> with the same ID. That is why in the add_row() function, it was just getting the value from the first instance of <tr> in the DOM.

I did not include the loop in the code snippet. Sorry for that.

Comment: So yeah, it was an XY problem then, as I suspected. Try not to overly simplify your questions, but add the relevant conditions to your questions so that people are able to construct an answer to the *actual* problem, and not some pseudo problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what it is you want. new_I seems to be your *"new text"*, correct?, so that's firstly what you should be console logging instead of "*new_E"*.

You also have some other things I want to point out. You set the values manually. Use the *placeholder* property instead for what you are doing here.

```js
function add_row()
{
    //Step 1: Getting what the user typed in the new row
    var new_E=document.getElementById("new_E").value;
    var new_I=document.getElementById("new_I").value;
    console.log("User typed this: "+ new_E+", in the first input field");
    console.log("User typed this: "+ new_I+", in the second input field");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="new_E" placeholder="Enter new text" value="test1">
<input type="text" id="new_I" placeholder="Enter new text" value="test2">
<button class="add" onclick="add_row()">Add row</button>
```

If what you meant was to *concatenate* the "new" value with the old value, so that they appear in the same console log, you can do the following:

```js
function add_row()
{
    //Step 1: Getting what the user typed in the new row
    var new_E=document.getElementById("new_E").value;
    var new_I=document.getElementById("new_I").value;
    console.log("User typed this: "+ new_E+" "+new_I);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="new_E" placeholder="Enter new text" value="test1">
<input type="text" id="new_I" placeholder="Enter new text" value="test2">
<button class="add" onclick="add_row()">Add row</button>
```

This could be a possible [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Did you simplify your question in hopes of getting an answer that could possibly help you solve a problem concerning something else/more?